# json response in restapi of laravel showing special characters

Tags: php, laravel

check this image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbTiQ.png) so  i want to merge two objects in laravel controller , first of all check my code

```
$output = [];

foreach ($vehicles as $key => $vehicle) 
{
    $center_lat = $lat;
    $center_lng = $lon;
    $lat=$vehicle->lat;
    $lng=$vehicle->lon;

    $vehicle->distance = haversineGreatCircleDistance($center_lat, $center_lng, $lat, $lng, 6371);
    
    $abc_id= $vehicle->abc_id;
    $abc=DB::table('tbl')->where('id',$abc)->get();

    $output [$key] = $vehicle;
    $result[] = array_merge((array)$output[$key],(array)$abc);
               
}
          
    return $result;
}
```

this works fine but it dosen't return in json fornmat and use special characters , acording to above code my output is like that

```
 {
        "id": 1,
        "abc_id": "1",
        "distance": 3834.5607952869,"
 [
then it use special characters and add abc array
            {
                "id": 3,
...
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

but i want my output like this

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    .....
    "distance": 5054.9836252887335,
    "abc": {
      "id": 2,
       .....
    }
]
```

can you guide me through this , sorry i am new in that technology

Comment: what special characters, can you show examples please?

Comment: *�*�items these are special characters

Comment: i update my question where i add a link of image check it out